# How Do I Recover A RabbitMQ Queue

Tags: rabbitmq, message-queue

I was taking a look at the queues with old messages and while trying to purge a queue I accidentally deleted deleted from RabbitMQ anyone know away to recover it?

Comment: do you what recover the name and bindings?

Comment: yes i would like too at least recover that much since it's an error capture queue i don't care about the messages.

Comment: Does this question belong on ` Super User.` rather than `Stack Overflow`?

Comment: If you have no exported definitions and no scripts that create and bind queue, then nope. At least it is less likely. Maybe you have some staging or dev server with same configuration and you can take queue params from there?

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the answers and help. I resolved the problem by recreating the queue and binding it to the exchange.